# Can you write an event function for scipy.integrate.solve_ivp that is terminal after some number of events?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to solve an IVP and stop the integration after N events have occured, e.g. 5 maxima. I know how to write the event to get one maximum, or all the maxima in a tspan, but not how to stop after 5 events.

There doesn't seem to be a way to store events from the event function itself; this is called many times when root finding.

I tried making the event terminal, then restarting the integration from the last point, but since this point makes the event trigger, you can't get past it. It does work to add a tiny epsilon past the event point, but that feels klugey. In this case, since the first derivative is 0 there, its not very wrong, but neither right.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/14771).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than just adding a tiny epsilon is to integrate (with no event) from the last event to a small epsilon after the event, then integrate from there with an event function. That way the solution is always consistent.